# ruby on rails skip_before_action has no affect in my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use the before_action in application_controller.rb and then some `skip_before_action`s to prevent some sites from being called before a user is logged in.

But the defined function in my application_controller.erb is not called ...

application_controller.erb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  layout "application"

  before_action :user_logged_in, :set_locale

  private

  def set_locale
     I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  # Prüft ob ein Nutzer eingeloggt ist.
  def user_logged_in

    puts "HA"

    if session[:user_id].nil?
      flash[:error] = "error"
      redirect_to :controller => :startsites, :action => :index
    else
      flash[:error] = "ok"
      redirect_to :controller => :startsites, :action => :index
    end

  end
end
```

The puts "HA" in `user_logged_in` is not printed in my server console. So I think the function is not called yet .. but why?

And in some controllers I tried to use this:

```
class MoviesController < ActionController::Base
    skip_before_action :user_logged_in, only: [:index, :show]
also not working ... why?
```

Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

Comment: try change `class MoviesController < ActionController::Base` to `class MoviesController < ApplicationController`. Because its not finding it. your `Movies` controller directly goes `ActionController`.

Comment: if its helped, can u accept the answer thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call through `ActionController`. Its not possible that way, as you built it.

```
 ActionController::Base
  -ApplicationController #your method in this controller

 ActionController::Base
  -MoviesController #yr trying to skip it right here
```

To skip it, you have to inherit like below:

```
ActionController::Base
 -ApplicationController #yr method is here
  --MoviesController #it will find that method and skip it.
```

**Controllers**

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end


# movies_controller.rb
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
end
```